# Repositioning a WXpython bitmap image

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to change the current position of a bitmap button or a bitmap image by clicking on another button in same panel, I have been searching for a function to do so. Please if anybody could provide me with a solution.

Comment: problem solved,we can use 

button_name.setPosition(wx.Point(x,y))

to change the position of button/bitmapbutton dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the OP in comments, there is a method on a button to do this.  It is called SetPosition()

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        super(Test,self).__init__(parent,title=title,size=(800,800))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.panel,1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)

        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Press Me")

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

        self.Show()


    def OnLeftDown(self, e):
        x, y = e.GetPosition()
        self.button.SetPosition(wx.Point(x,y))
        print x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None,title='TEST')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I posted this answer so the question shows up in the list as having an answer :)